# Can somebody explain participant, identity, wallet's meaning and their relationship for composer playground?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm learning Hyperledger Composer, and very confused about the concept of participant, identity, wallet and their relationship with real busineas world.

can somebody explain it ? it's best to have some examples.

Comment: why many identities can added to a wallet? I think a wallet should belong to only a end user. one identity is one end user.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope you have read the documentation, particularly:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/glossary.html
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/participantsandidentities.html

Participants are people or systems that can access a business network. A Participant is a modelled class in Composer, and has state stored on the blockchain to represent it. This gives Composer a very powerful notion of "users" or "organisations" as the model for these (including relationships) is entirely under the control of the designer of the business network.

A Participant uses an Identity (certificate) to authenticate to Fabric and to prove who they are. In Composer an admin maps the public key certificate for a Participant ID using the `issue identity`, `revoke identity`, `bind identity` commands.